# Browser won't render iframe because it thinks it is over HTTP (with Tomcat and IIS setup)

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, iis, iframe

For our webapp, we have a resource that is being rendered in an iframe as part of a Jasper Reports.  The content is html.  When I load the primary page, it shows the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.com/reports/report1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://myapp.com/reports/report1.html?decorator=report&format=html&view=Show+Report&types[Profile].selected=1234-1234-1234-1234'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

When I inspect the iframe in the chrome dev tools, the `src=` attribute starts at the `?format=html...`, and when I hover over that field it gives the full path with https.

I don't know why the web browser thinks that the resource being served is http, or how it would be possible that it could be served as http.  When I access the resource directly, taking the path of the iframe in another window and in another browser, the content gets served fine.  And when I use the same url with http instead of https, it returns the content in https.

---

Here's some issues I've been able to find that seem to be related:

- [Chrome iFrame Block HTTPS redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705920/chrome-iframe-block-https-redirect?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe include the *jasperreports* tag? Seems relevant.

Comment: Look at the actual code for the site rather than what the browser tools show you. Many times browsers will adjust the actual HTML or other code if it's invalid or non-compliant, etc.

Comment: We need to see your actual code to know what the issue is here; voting to close as No MCVE.